# How to import and transform metadata in shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, metadata, iso-19115

I know nothing about metadata so my question will seem a bit dumb.

I found metadata on the net that I want to use in a shapefile in QGIS, but I have no idea on how to do it. I tried the metatools plugin in QGIS, but I need shapefiles to incorporate the metadata. So I create a new shapefile and I was able to import/create metadata for this new shapefile. But now I don't know what to do to see the data, as a shapefile.

Here the metadata that I search to see: https://phd.dream.upd.edu.ph/layers/geonode%3Apanay_streamnetworks_final and I downloaded the ISO form because it can be used with metatools.

Comment: What you found is metadata and data

Answer (score 1):

We all have to start somewhere.

Meta-data can best be described as a small report / description providing information about a specific dataset.

So its data describing data.

It is best practice when distributing information (in this case spatial information) to provide a metadata file within the data package. this information describes who generated the information, what projection was used, how the data was generated...etc... basically information which will help a user months / years down the line understand the thought process as to how this information was generated.

There are different types of "formats" - i.e. ISO and FGDC
There are also different programs / add-ins / plugins around that are designed to make the process of capturing this metadata easier. I have a feeling the tool you used was to help in preparing the meta data for a dataset.

If you want more info...here is a link:
[Metadata](https://www.fgdc.gov/metadata)

Getting back to your question, you cannot convert meta data to a spatial dataset - as far as I am aware. Maybe if there were spatial coordinates stored as text you could...but generally you can't.
The link you provided appears to be of a viewer for this particular dataset / agency.

The best bet would be to try and contact the originator of the information to get a copy of the Geodatabase / Shapefile of the streams layer being presented. It appears the site needs a login, so getting a login may provide you with more options to get access to background information.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS is the only software system I can think of that incorporates metadata directly into the data system, and so now everyone who thinks of 'metadata' and 'spatial data' expects there to be a system like the ArcGIS metadata system.

Every other non-spatial data system I've seen that has any metadata at all has no such concept of integrated metadata into the tables. They simply have spreadsheets or other reports that document that tables, columns, etc.

My suggestion would be to build up a repository / spreadsheet that lists the tables such as the Panay Streem Networks, and the associated metadata in columns of information such as Abstract, Publication Date, Type, etc.